# How did I have two different public keys for one e-mail address

Tags: pgp

I created public/private keypair with Mailvelope Chrome plugin. I don't fully remember the details but I exported the public key and sent it to MIT keyserver. After few weeks, I realized that my public key on MIT server and the public key on Mailvelope are different. I tried to encrypt an e-mail with both public keys and sent to myself, Mailvelope successfully decrypted both of them. So, my questions are:

1. Why the public key on MIT server is different. Was it my mistake or there is another process on MIT server?
2. How my private key could be able do decrypt two different e-mails which are encrypted with two different public keys?

Comment: Could you share the keys or some more details? There are some pitfalls when comparing public keys so that they might appear to you as being different when they actually contain the same information.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that the keys are in fact different. As the comments did already point out, there are pitfalls when comparing keys manually that can lead to the false conclusion they'd be different. Those include:

- The two keys are differently encoded but hold the same information
- You compare different hash types of the same key

Generally speaking, you can have a (finite, but for all practical considerations) unlimited number of key pairs. If Mailvelope instead of exporting your public key created a new key pair and exported that public key, you can decrypt both messages as you hold both private keys.

There also is a feature (I think Mailvelope does not support it) that is called sub keys, which are regular key pairs associated with your main key pair.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to decrypt data encrypted with both keys (and you have only one private key), then those two keys are actually the same.

My guess is that one of the keys you are seeing is actually a subkey. On modern PGP keys the setup is:

```
pub   4096R/AAAAAAAA 2017-12-01
uid                  John Doe <jdoe@example.com>
sub   4096R/11112222 2017-12-01
```

Here, you have a PGP key 0xAAAAAAAA with an encryption subkey 0x11112222. When you choose 0xAAAAAAAA as a recipient, you will be actually be encrypting to the 0x11112222 subkey. Depending on the message, one or other could be displayed, getting a bit confusing (encrypted to 0x11112222? I expected to encrypt it to john key, which is 0xAAAAAAAA!).

Also, beware when encrypting to perform tests like this, that when sending a message, it will (typically) also encrypt it to the sender's key (so he can read what he sent), so you could be inadvertently be decrypting it not because you have the recipient key, but because another key was also automatically included.